# Need a common date format function which support Oracle and Postgre sql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I am using a date function trunc in Oracle, and date_trunc in Postgre which is working fine and matching results. I am trying to use the common single query which should support both Oracle as well as Postgre sql. Can I have some inputs please, With to_char function it is giving some unmatched results.

here is my queries;
/*Oracle*/
select * from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno=d.deptno and trunc(sysdate)<=trunc(joining_date);

/*Postgre sql*/
select * from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno=d.deptno and date_trunc('day', current_date)<=trunc('day',joining_date);

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to have the same code for different RDBMS. They support different functions and you should use the appropriate functions for each RDBMS.

---

If you must (but I'm sure you don't actually have to) then you can use `EXTRACT` in both databases:

```sql
select *
from   emp e
       inner join dept d
       on     e.deptno=d.deptno
          and (       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM joining_date)
              or (    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM joining_date)
                  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date) < EXTRACT(MONTH FROM joining_date))
              or (    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM joining_date)
                  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM joining_date)
                  AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM current_date) <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM joining_date))
              )
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NRaGjfS6) [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IBaqD2fD)

However, that feels like you are trying too hard to get something that works for both databases rather than using the appropriate functions in each individual database.

Comment: Thank you for the input/suggestion and your help here.  it helped me